# Rails+Backbone.js - dynamical loading templates for mustache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, mustache

**Hi**

Please anyone tell me how to load a mustache template **from other file** into my backbone script?
I'd tried a Ajax but he loads it to me too late and view is already prepared... 
Anyway... how to load **assets/templates/single/index.html.mustache** into backbone View and redirect it into **View** @el element?

*Many thanks*

Answer (score 0):

Actually, haven't been able to find a gem similar to handlebars_assets for mustache. Maybe something similar for mustache since handlebars is an extension of mustache.

https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets